# How to add values and ignore non values in a list using python?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the mean of all the numbers in the list, one problem is it keeps on giving me an error because I may believe it does not allow the program to add non integer values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('train.csv')
result = df[(df.Sex=='female') & (df.Pclass==3)]
list_of_ages = []
list_of_ages = '\n'.join(str(x) for x in result.Age)

for v in list_of_ages:
    average_value = sum(v) / len(v)


print(list_of_ages)
```

when I print all the values of the list , it shows this.

```
26.0
27.0
4.0
14.0
31.0
nan
15.0
8.0
38.0
nan
nan
18.0
14.0
40.0
19.0
nan
18.0
17.0
16.0
30.0
nan
33.0
28.0
21.0
nan
14.5
20.0
17.0
2.0
nan
47.0
nan
22.0
24.0
9.0
16.0
45.0
1.0
nan
4.0
nan
19.0
nan
2.0
16.0
27.0
nan
5.0
nan
nan
nan
25.0
29.0
41.0
29.0
nan
nan
45.0
35.0
22.0
24.0
nan
26.0
31.0
nan
nan
nan
nan
45.0
nan
nan
3.0
22.0
1.0
24.0
31.0
21.0
20.0
nan
nan
10.0
28.0
nan
21.0
5.0
0.75
22.0
2.0
63.0
nan
21.0
nan
37.0
nan
30.0
9.0
11.0
22.0
36.0
nan
29.0
nan
nan
nan
39.0
nan
26.0
9.0
41.0
2.0
0.75
23.0
nan
18.0
32.0
18.0
43.0
nan
4.0
nan
18.0
nan
25.0
48.0
30.5
5.0
13.0
18.0
nan
31.0
30.0
18.0
6.0
23.0
27.0
15.0
9.0
18.0
24.0
nan
15.0
22.0
39.0
nan
```

I just want to sum all the values , ignore the non float value and find the mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your code, one of them is that `list_of_ages` is not actually a list, but a string.

Putting that aside, you can simply use `pandas.Series.mean()` method:

```
result = df[(df.Sex=='female') & (df.Pclass==3)]
mean_age = result.Age.mean()
```